# remove duplicate coordinates from X and Y column

Tags: r, dplyr

Based on the data below how can I remove the rows with duplicate `X` and `Y` `coordinates`? In the example below, you will notice that one of `X` coordinate is `-1.52` which is repeated `twice` but it's not a duplicate since it's corresponding `Y` coordiantes are different.

I don't know if it matters but please note that the orginal dataset has more than `2` decimal places for the X and Y values.

Sample data:

```
structure(list(id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10), X = c(-1.01, 
-1.11, -1.11, -2.13, -2.13, -1.52, -1.52, -1.98, -3.69, -4.79), 
    Y = c(2.11, 3.33, 3.33, 6.66, 6.66, 7.77, 8.88, 9.99, 1.11, 
    6.68)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Desired data:

```
id X     Y
1  -1.01 2.11
2  -1.11 3.33
4  -2.13 6.66
6  -1.52 7.77
7  -1.52 8.88
8  -1.98 9.99
9  -3.69 1.11
19 -4.79 6.68
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `duplicated`

```
subset(df1, !duplicated(df1[-1]))
```

-output

```
    id     X    Y
1   1 -1.01 2.11
2   2 -1.11 3.33
4   4 -2.13 6.66
6   6 -1.52 7.77
7   7 -1.52 8.88
8   8 -1.98 9.99
9   9 -3.69 1.11
10 10 -4.79 6.68
```

---

Or with `distinct`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   distinct(X, Y, .keep_all = TRUE)
```